PyTorch Lightningでforward関数に引数が正しく渡されないエラーについて
本質問は以下のサイトでも質問しています:
https://teratail.com/questions/ginz4nnicg10c9
pytorch_lightningを使用していて，以下のエラーが出ています：
TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'masks'．
しかし，forwardには適切に因数を渡しているように思えます．エラーの原因がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたらお気軽にご回答いただけますと幸いです．
具体的なコードの一部とエラーメッセージは以下の通りです．ほかにも参照したい箇所がある方は遠慮なくおっしゃってください．
###############
### Dataset ###
###############
class VideoDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, df_list, df, tokenizer, bert_model, max_length, comment_batch_size, num_layers, lstm_dropout, lstm_batch_size, lstm_hidden_size, j, frame_batch_size, num_heads, video_batch_size, d=768):
        self.comment_processor = CommentProcessor(d, num_layers, lstm_dropout,  lstm_batch_size, lstm_hidden_size)  
        self.title_desc_processor = TitleDescProcessor(d, df, tokenizer, bert_model, max_length, batch_size=32)  
        self.get_j_frames = GetJFrames(j, frame_batch_size, video_batch_size=1, d=768)  
        self.video_processor = VideoProcessor(d, num_heads, video_batch_size)

        self.df_list = df_list
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.bert_model = bert_model
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.comment_batch_size = comment_batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df_list)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # 各データをstackして返す
        df = self.df_list[idx]
        # 動画によってコメント数が違う→バッチサイズが異なる→スタックできない→padding
        comment_embeddings = get_comment_embedding(df, self.tokenizer, self.bert_model, self.max_length, self.comment_batch_size)
        comment_output_avg = self.comment_processor(comment_embeddings)
        hit_likes = torch.tensor(df['like_count'].values, dtype=torch.float16)
        title_desc_output_avg = self.title_desc_processor()
        top_j_sim_video_embeddings_list = self.get_j_frames()
        video_output_avg = self.video_processor(top_j_sim_video_embeddings_list)
        
        label = df['label'].values
        label = torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.float16)
        # 自動的にlabelは(batch_size,)の形状にして渡される

        return comment_output_avg, hit_likes, title_desc_output_avg, video_output_avg, label

    
def collate_fn(batch):
    # バッチ内の全ての要素からコメントテンソルを取得し、最大のコメント数を計算
    max_comments = max([comments.size(0) for comments, _, _, _, _ in batch])
    padded_comments = []
    masks = []

    # バッチ内の各要素に対してパディングとマスク処理を実施
    for comments, hit_likes, title_desc_embeddings, video_output, label in batch:
        pad_size = max_comments - comments.size(0)
        mask = torch.ones(comments.size(0), dtype=torch.bool)
        if pad_size > 0:
            pad_tensor = torch.zeros(pad_size, comments.size(1), comments.size(2), dtype=comments.dtype)
            comments = torch.cat([comments, pad_tensor], dim=0)
            pad_mask = torch.zeros(pad_size, dtype=torch.bool)
            mask = torch.cat([mask, pad_mask], dim=0)
        padded_comments.append(comments)
        masks.append(mask)

    # リストをTensorに変換
    padded_comments_stack = torch.stack(padded_comments, dim=0)
    masks_stack = torch.stack(masks, dim=0)
    hit_likes = torch.stack([hit_likes for _, hit_likes, _, _, _ in batch], dim=0)
    title_desc_embeddings = torch.stack([title_desc_embeddings for _, _, title_desc_embeddings, _, _ in batch], dim=0)
    video_output_stack = torch.stack([video_output for _, _, _, video_output, _ in batch], dim=0)
    labels = torch.stack([label for _, _, _, _, label in batch], dim=0)
    
    return padded_comments_stack, masks_stack, hit_likes, title_desc_embeddings, video_output_stack, labels



#############
### Class ###
#############
class FakeNewsDetector(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, bert_model, random_state, max_length, batch_size, num_workers, lr, n_split, dropout_rate, lstm_dropout, input_size, lstm_hidden_size, hidden_dim, num_layers, bidirectional, num_heads, max_epochs, patience, fig_save_name, name, weight_decay, d=768):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters(ignore=['tokenizer', 'bert_model'])

        self.validation_step_outputs = []
        self.d = d

        self.video_fc = nn.Linear(2*d, 2*d)

        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(max_length * 2*d, 1024)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1024)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, 128)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(128, 1)

        self.comment_weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1))
        self.title_desc_weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1))
        self.video_weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1))

        self.bilstm_model = BiLSTM(input_size=int(input_size), hidden_size=int(lstm_hidden_size),
                                    num_layers=int(num_layers), dropout=float(lstm_dropout))
        self.bilstm_model = self.bilstm_model.to('cuda')

        self.comment_processor = CommentProcessor(d, num_layers, lstm_dropout, lstm_batch_size, lstm_hidden_size=768//2)
        self.title_desc_processor = TitleDescProcessor(d)
        self.get_j_frames = GetJFrames()
        self.video_processor = VideoProcessor()

    def forward(self, comment_embeddings, masks_stack, hit_likes, title_desc_embedding, video_output_stack):

        comment_output_avg = self.comment_processor(comment_embeddings)
        # shape: (batch_size, 2*d)

        title_desc_output_avg = self.title_desc_processor(title_desc_embedding)
        # shape: (batch_size, 2*d)

        top_j_sim_video_embeddings_list = self.get_j_frames(common_ids_list)
        video_output_avg = self.video_processor(top_j_sim_video_embeddings_list)
        # shape: (1, 2*d)

        weights = F.softmax(torch.stack([self.comment_weight, self.title_desc_weight, self.video_weight]), dim=0)


        combined_output = weights[0] * comment_output_avg + weights[1] * title_desc_output_avg + weights[2] * video_output_avg


        x = self.flatten(combined_output)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        
        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        x = x.squeeze()  # 不要な次元を削除して形状を(batch_size,)にする
        return x
    
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        comment_embeddings, masks, hit_likes, title_desc_embedding, weighted_avg_video_embedding, label = batch
        output = self(comment_embeddings, masks, hit_likes, title_desc_embedding, weighted_avg_video_embedding)
        loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(output, label)
        self.log('train_loss', loss)

        return loss
    
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        comment_embeddings, masks, hit_likes, title_desc_embedding, weighted_avg_video_embedding, label = batch
        output = self(comment_embeddings, masks, hit_likes, title_desc_embedding, weighted_avg_video_embedding)
        
        loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(output, label)
        self.log('val_loss', loss)

        label_predicted = output

        label_predicted = label_predicted.cpu().numpy()
        label = label.cpu().numpy()
        logits = torch.logit(output).cpu().numpy()

        self.validation_step_outputs.append({'label': label, 'label_predicted': label_predicted, 'logits': logits})

        accuracy = accuracy_score(label, label_predicted)
        f1 = f1_score(label, label_predicted)
        precision = precision_score(label, label_predicted)
        recall = recall_score(label, label_predicted)

        self.log('val_acc', accuracy)
        self.log('val_f1', f1)
        self.log('val_precision', precision)
        self.log('val_recall', recall)

        return loss

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):
        all_label = []
        all_preds = []
        all_pred_probs = []

        for output in self.validation_step_outputs:
            all_label.extend(output['label'])
            all_preds.extend(output['logits'])
            all_pred_probs.extend(output['label_predicted'])
        
        cm = confusion_matrix(all_label, all_preds)
        for i in range(cm.shape[0]):
            for j in range(cm.shape[1]):
                self.log(f'val_cm_{i}_{j}', float(cm[i, j]))

        auc = roc_auc_score(all_label, all_pred_probs)
        self.log('val_AUC', auc)

        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(all_label, all_pred_probs)

        plot_roc_curve(fpr, tpr, random_state, self.batch_size, self.max_length, self.fig_save_path, fig_save_name='test_roc')
        plot_fpr_threshold(thresholds, fpr, random_state, self.batch_size, self.max_length, self.fig_save_path, fig_save_name='test_fpr')
        plot_tpr_threshold(thresholds, tpr, random_state, self.batch_size, self.max_length, self.fig_save_path, fig_save_name='test_tpr')

        self.validation_step_outputs.clear()

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = AdamW(self.parameters(), lr=self.hparams.lr, weight_decay=self.hparams.weight_decay)
        return optimizer




#####################
### Error message ###
#####################
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 16
      8 logger = TensorBoardLogger(
      9     save_dir="lightning_logs",
     10     name=name,
     11     version=f"Fold_{fold+1}"
     12     )
     14 trainer = make_trainer(max_epochs, logger, name, patience)
---> 16 trainer.fit(model, train_loader, val_loader)
     18 val_results = trainer.validate(model, val_loader)
     20 val_losses.append(val_results[0]['val_loss'])

File ~/anaconda3/envs/choi_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py:532, in Trainer.fit(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    530 self.strategy._lightning_module = model
    531 _verify_strategy_supports_compile(model, self.strategy)
--> 532 call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
    533     self, self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
    534 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/choi_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py:43, in _call_and_handle_interrupt(trainer, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
     41     if trainer.strategy.launcher is not None:
     42         return trainer.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=trainer, **kwargs)
---> 43     return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     45 except _TunerExitException:
...
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda3/envs/choi_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'masks'

環境は以下の通りです：
Ubuntu 20.04
VSCode==1.89
PyTorch==2.1.2
pytorch-lightning==2.0.8

至急改善したいです．お気軽にご回答のほどよろしくお願いいたします．

他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？

ありがとうございます。マルチポストという概念を知りませんでした。ご教授いただきありがとうございます！
